# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to Automate a regular procedure using Java with Selenium. I tried to use Chrome as my browser. But I am getting an error and can't able to load the browser.

Below is the error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.3) on port 52793 Exception in thread "main"
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally (Driver info:  chromedriver=2.3,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 22.50 seconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
```

**Chrome version used**: Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Code used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {   
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Automation\\Thomas_Auto\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://vrijuit.nl/nl/vakanties");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.basic-sprite.date")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'1')])[56]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-state-default.ui-state-active.ui-state-hover")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("info & prijs")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.btn.btn-select")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-call-to-action")).click();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3ox3.jpg)

Comment: The error while chrome browser loads:

Disable developer mode extensions

Extensions running inn developer mode can harm your computer. If you are not a developer, you should disable these extensions running in developer mode to stay safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your ChromeDriver and chrome to latest version and try again.

I ran your code with ChromeDriver version 2.35 and chrome Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) on my environment and there was no issue.

You can disable extensions via chromeoptions.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
    ChromeDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Sijin, It works .. Is this problem arise due to version change?

Comment: It might be caused due to some extensions on chrome with developer mode enabled.
The warning "Disable developer mode extensions" is displayed in Chrome when you install non Chrome Web Store extensions in the browser.it displays the warning because chrome thinks that some malware force-installed the extensions to Chrome

Comment: Thanks Sijin. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ChromeDriver doesn't support `driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Try ChromeOptions to achieve the same ...e.g.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D://Automation/Thomas_Auto/Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, 

         Thanks, but it didn't work. Please note I am getting an error while loading chrome browser. Below is the error.

'**"Disable developer mode extensions Extensions running inn developer mode can harm your computer. If you are not a developer, you should disable these extensions running in developer mode to stay safe"**' 

Can you plz help on this. Is that required to disable developer option. If yes, plz let me know how to do that.

Comment: Please refer the attached image.